# How often is the information updated in the flairs?

Tags: support

Hi. I would like to share a flair in my webpage but I noticed that the reputation they display is not current. (And the default theme displays a different reputation than the others.)

I am not sure whether this is a problem on my end or a bug, or simply that the information is only updated every so often. Any idea what is the case?

(If it matters, I have an Ibook and run Firefox.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Why is my flair not updated with my actual reputation score?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69401/flair-not-updated/69403#69403)

> Flair is updated every 24-36 hours. Just wait.

Comment: Many thanks! (And also thanks for retagging this appropriately!)